# Remote uninstall of office 2016 via powershell

Tags: powershell

We are in an enterprise enviroment and are slowly upgrading all of our endusers from office 2016 -> Office 365. I am running into trouble coming up with a PS script that removes the office 2016 and all of its associated applications (word 2016, outlook 2016, etc. Any help is appreciated.

```
$computerName = "COMPUTERNAMEHERE"
$yourAccount = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $yourAccount -ScriptBlock {
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | Select Name
}
$computerName = "COMPUTERNAMEHERE"
$appName = "Microsoft office 2016 professional plus"
$yourAccount = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $yourAccount -ScriptBlock {
Get-WmiObject Win32_product | Where {$_.name -eq $appName} | ForEach {
    $_.Uninstall()
   }
}
```

Comment: [Please Stop Using Win32_Product To Find Installed Software. Alternatives Inside!](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/)

Comment: You know you can advice the installer of Office 365 to uninstall all previous versions of Office, don't you?

Comment: Are you getting some error with this ?